# Is the normed space of bounded convergent sequences closed?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis

Suppose we have the normed space of bounded real sequences with the uniform norm. Is the subset consisting of convergent sequences closed?

Comment: Yes, it is.  Where did you get stuck in trying to prove it?

Comment: Let's call the subset $X$. Suppose $\{x_n\}$ is a convergent sequence in $X$ with limit $x$. So I am trying to show that $x$ is convergent. I have no idea what to do from here...

Comment: Try showing instead that $x$ is Cauchy.

Comment: Well, I know that for all $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $ n > N $ implies $||x_n - x||_\infty < \epsilon $ so $sup_k |x^k_n - x^k| < \epsilon$. But how does that help in showing that $x$ is Cauchy?

Comment: All you really need is that there exists $y \in X$ with $\|y-x\|_{\infty} < \epsilon$, or perhaps $\epsilon /3$, and $y$ convergent/Cauchy.

Comment: And I have such a $y$. Just pick any of the $x_n$. But how does that show $x$ is Cauchy?

Comment: Fix $\epsilon > 0$.  You have to find an $N$ such that... something something... holds for $x$.  But you can choose an $N$ such that... something something... holds for $y$.  And you know that for any $k$, $|x^k - y^k| < \epsilon/3$ or something...

Comment: May not be too hard to show the complement, containing unbounded divergent sequences is open.

Comment: Thanks, Nate! I have it. =)

Answer (score 0):

Let $S=\{0,1,1/2,1/3,1/4,\cdots\}$. Then $S$ is a compact set in the relative topology of $[0,1]$; hence $C(S)$ is a Banach space under the usual sup norm.

Every $f \in C(S)$ defines a convergent sequence $\{ x_{n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ by $x_{n}=f(1/n)$ with $\lim_{n} x_{n}=f(0)$. Conversely, if $\{ x_{n} \}$ is a convergent sequence, then $f(1/n)=x_{n}$, $f(0)=\lim_{n}x_{n}$ defines $f \in C(S)$. The norm of $f \in C(S)$ is the same as $\sup_{n} |x_{n}|$.